# In python how to get all the values in an array of elements from json

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is the json with array of elements. How to get all the name values in a array? Is there a simplar way of doing it without for loop.

```
import json
from unicodedata import name

# Define json variable
jsondata = """[
 {
  "name":"Pen",
  "unit_price":5
 },
 {
  "name":"Eraser",
  "unit_price":3
 },
 {
  "name":"Pencil",
  "unit_price":10
 },
 {
  "name":"White paper",
  "unit_price":15
 }
]"""

# load the json data
items = json.loads(jsondata)
namelist = []
for keyval in items:
    namelist.append((keyval['name']))

print(namelist)
```

Comment: Use list comprehension `namelist = [ x['name'] for x in items ]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
names = [it['name'] for it in items]
```